# Событие при вызове диспетчера задач

Tags: python, tkinter, input

Возник вопрос при создании программы, использую Python и модуль Tkinter. Основная цель сделать так, чтобы при нажатии сочетания клавиш Ctrl + Alt + Delete происходило определенное действие, к примеру исполнялся такой код:

```
mb.showinfo("INFO", "Вы попытались вызвать диспетчер задач")
```

Были идеи создать это все примерно так:

```
def call(event):
    mb.showinfo("INFO", "Вы попытались вызвать диспетчер задач")

root = Tk()
root.update()
root.bind('<Control-Alt-Delete>', call)
```

Но в результате данный код был проигнорирован программой. Заранее благодарю за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+del', lambda: mb.showinfo("INFO", "Вы попытались вызвать диспетчер задач"))
```

А чтоб перекрыть добавьте `suppress = True`.
Че трояны пописываем? ;)

Comment: Да порой просто интересно становиться как все работает, вот и решил сам написать) Естественно только в целях изучения. Большое спасибо за решение

Comment: @Developman Да я понимаю, я шучу. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вот также способ для отмены закрытия:

```
def on_closing():
    if (ms.askokcancel('Выход', 'У тебя не получится выйти')):
       ms.showerror('Ха-ха', 'Я же говорил)')
tk.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```